# Spring @Scheduled Annotation for Inherited Classes

Tags: spring, inheritance, annotations, aop, scheduler

I am trying to use @Scheduled annotation for a service layer class. The class also gets monitored by a logging service through AOP.

When I make the service class implement an interface, Spring throws the error

```
Error creating bean with name 'dummyService' defined in file
......
......
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to prepare task
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.doWith(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:452)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:430)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $Proxy23.run()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:178)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.doWith(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:111)
    ... 17 more
```

This is the service layer class:

```
package com.mydomain.web.myapp.service;
@Service
public class DummyService implements DummyI{
        @Scheduled(cron = "${some.cron.time}")
        public void run() {
        }
}
```

If I remove the inheritance, it works without problem. Why is that?

This is what I have for the logging service :

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingServiceImpl implements LoggingService {
        private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        @Around("execution(* com.mydomain.web.myapp..*.*(..))")
        public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here:

- Add `run()` to `DummyI` interface
- Create another interface having only `run()` method (or use [`java.lang.Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)) and implemented that interface as well:

  ```
  public class DummyService implements DummyI, Runnable
  ```
- Enable class based ([cglib](/questions/tagged/cglib)) proxies